# Detect Same Class using C++ template

Tags: c++

How is below code working to detect if the two classes are same? Specially I did not get the syntax second IsSame class. It does not look like the explicit initialization. Please let me know which link I should go through to understand this? I am following book 'C++ the complete reference' by Robbert Schildit.

```
template<typename A, typename B> struct IsSame {
    static const bool same = false;
};
template<typename A> struct IsSame<A, A> {//have confusion here
    static const bool same = true;
};

template<typename A, typename B> bool IsSameClass() {
    return IsSame<A, B>::same;
}

int main(void)
{
  cout << IsSameClass<vector<int>, vector<int>>();//returns 1
  cout << IsSameClass<vector<int>, vector<float>>();//returns 0
}
```

Comment: Look at [partial_template_specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).

Comment: Thanks. Got my answer.

Comment: `IsSameClass` is a misleading name, since it would work for non-class types as well (e.g., `IsSameClass<long, int64_t>()`).

Comment: Be aware when checking types, that templates are handled on compile-time, so runtime polymorphism won't work because the types of the pointer variables will be checked, even when checking the dereferenced pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The first definition of `IsSame` is a *primary template*. The second one is its *partial specialization*.

When you use `IsSame` within `IsSameClass`, if template arguments match the partial specialization (i.e., if both arguments represent the same type) then this partial specialization is *instantiated* and the function returns its `same` value which is `true`. Otherwise, the primary template is instantiated and function returns `false`.